# Attempting to center a nav menu through media queries but not responding

Tags: html, css, css-float, media-queries

I am creating a banner on a responsive website and at certain screen size I would like the navigation menu (which is normally floated to the right of the banner) to be centered. The nav bar seems to respond to other sorts of changes within the media query (color, size, etc) but I cannot figure out how to center the entire ul.

```css
/* line 8, ../scss/header.scss */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* line 13, ../scss/header.scss */
.banner {
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80px;
}

/* line 19, ../scss/header.scss */
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* line 24, ../scss/header.scss */
.left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
}

/* line 29, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col {
  float: right;
  width: 77%;
  text-align: right;
}
/* line 34, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1.5px solid;
}
/* line 39, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
/* line 42, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  /* line 51, ../scss/header.scss */
  .banner {
    height: 160;
    background-color: red;
  }

  /* line 55, ../scss/header.scss */
  .left-col, .right-col {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* line 60, ../scss/header.scss */
  .right-col {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* line 67, ../scss/header.scss */
  .right-col li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
  }

  /* line 74, ../scss/header.scss */
  .right-col ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/* This is the clear fix method */
/* line 91, ../scss/header.scss */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

/* line 96, ../scss/header.scss */
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 100, ../scss/header.scss */
.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<html>
 <div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="left-col">
    <p>HEADER</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-col">
    <nav class="site-nav">
     <ul class="group">
      <li><a href="contact.html" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#methodology">Methodology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="draft1-1.html">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is likely to blame.

Changing the CSS declaration in the media query from `.right-col li` to `.right-col .site-nav li` seems to do the trick.

Also, removing the `float: right` from `.right-col .site-nav li` and changing the display to `display: inline-block` will keep the ordering intact.

```css
/* line 8, ../scss/header.scss */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* line 13, ../scss/header.scss */
.banner {
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80px;
}

/* line 19, ../scss/header.scss */
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* line 24, ../scss/header.scss */
.left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
}

/* line 29, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col {
  float: right;
  width: 77%;
  text-align: right;
}
/* line 34, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1.5px solid;
}
/* line 39, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
/* line 42, ../scss/header.scss */
.right-col .site-nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  /* line 51, ../scss/header.scss */
  .banner {
    height: 160;
    background-color: red;
  }

  /* line 55, ../scss/header.scss */
  .left-col, .right-col {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* line 60, ../scss/header.scss */
  .right-col {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* line 67, ../scss/header.scss */
   .right-col .site-nav li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
  }

  /* line 74, ../scss/header.scss */
  .right-col ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/* This is the clear fix method */
/* line 91, ../scss/header.scss */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

/* line 96, ../scss/header.scss */
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 100, ../scss/header.scss */
.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<html>
 <div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="left-col">
    <p>HEADER</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right-col">
    <nav class="site-nav">
     <ul class="group">
      <li><a href="contact.html" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#methodology">Methodology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="draft1-1.html">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I am seeing "change a to a"

Comment: Do you know of anyway to keep the ordering of the list intact when it centers?

Comment: Much appreciated - wasn't sure if it warranted a new questions.